# VMware - 64bit guest on Windows Home Premium

Tags: vmware, virtualization

I have a CPU supporting Intel VT-x, but VMware is refusing to run a 64bit guest operating system ("This host is VT-capable, but VT is disabled."). I think VT is enabled in the BIOS, so I'm wondering if my problem is related to Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit. Do I need Win7 Professional, or should this be working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as so often, the solution was "Have you tried turning it off and on again?". I took the following steps to fix the problem:

- Disabled VT in the BIOS (Advanced BIOS features -> CPU feature -> Virtualization)
- Boot, shutdown (cold restart)
- Re-enabled VT
- Boot, shutdown (cold restart)

Now VMware works as expected. So my problem definitely was not related to having Home Premium.

Comment: +1 My Windows Home Premium 64Bit runs Windows 2008R2 (64bit) with no issues